# Python: nested try catch handling

Tags: python, nested, try-catch

currently I have some code like this

```
try:
    somecode
except Exception as Error:
    fallbackcode
```

Now i want to add another fallback to the fallbackcode
Whats is the best practice to make a nested try/catch in python?

```
try:
    somecode
except Exception as Error:
    try:
        fallbackcode
    except Exception as Error:
        nextfallbackcode
```

produces intendation errors

Comment: *"produces intendation errors"* Nope, not if you do it right. We can't tell you what you did wrong because you didn't bother including a [mcve].

Comment: you were right, problem was an earlier indentation error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do nested try/except blocks exactly how you have it implemented in your question.

Here's another example:

```
import os

def touch_file(file_to_touch):
    """
    This method accepts a file path as a parameter and
    returns true/false if it successfully 'touched' the file
    :param '/path/to/file/'
    :return: True/False
    """    
    file_touched = True

    try:
        os.utime(file_to_touch, None)
    except EnvironmentError:
        try:
            open(file_to_touch, 'a').close()
        except EnvironmentError:
            file_touched = False

    return file_touched
```

Answer (score 3):

You can rewrite the logic using a loop provided all your callbacks and fallbacks have same API interface

```
for code in [somecode, fallbackcode, nextfallbackcode]:
    try:
        code(*args, **kwargs)
        break
    except Exception as Error:
        continue
else:
    raise HardException
```

This would be the preferred way instead of multiple level of nested exception blocks.

Comment: You forgot a `break`.

Answer (score 2):

you can use functions to handle errors :

```
def func0():
    try:
        somecode
    except:
        other_func()

def func1():
    try:
        somecode
    except:
        func0()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have change it like this:

```
try:
    try:
        somecode
    except Exception as Error:
        fallbackcode
except Exception as Error:
    nextfallbackcode
```